# Most efficient method for hand drawing and user input in XNA

Tags: c#, vector, xna, drawing

We've been working on a digital drawing system using XNA for display and using the Kinect as an input device. Right now we can use a variety of inputs to detect when a user wants to draw to the screen or manipulate objects, but I've hit a bit of a wall in displaying and sending the user input to the other networked systems.

Right now, we break up user input points into line segments (Vector2 and thin Rectangles) and draw those segments (sometimes of very small lengths) to the screen and send them to the networked tables. Unfortunately, this method doesn't exactly match what the user draws to the screen and we're getting bad quality with things like hand writing.

I've looked into SVG a bit but don't think thats the way to go, although I'm fairly confident that some sort of vectorization is the correct course of action. Does anyone have any experience with hand drawing in C#/XNA and can give some recommendations?

Comment: Perhaps some screenshots/diagrams would better explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smooth your input lines with Bezier curves.
Hopefully that should make the text readable.

Comment: That's what I've been recommended and the path I'm following with some deviations. Not exactly the detailed answer I was looking for but when I finish up what I'm writing I'll post it as an example to others looking to solve this problem.